# NOT IN is not taken in consideration

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query and the problem is that NOT IN is not taken in consideration

I'm trying to achive following. I wan't to fetch products from my DB where

1. stock_invoice_based = 0
2. deleted = 'false'
3. product_id != 42,45,46,48,52,82,86,123,173,176,181,196,196,202
4. And if any of following column is not "empty"
5. warehouse_row OR warehouse_column OR warehouse_ledge OR warehouse_id

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE shop_products (
  product_id int,
  stock_invoice_based int,
  deleted varchar(50),
  warehouse_row varchar(50),
  warehouse_column varchar(50),
  warehouse_ledge varchar(50),
  warehouse_id varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO shop_products (product_id, stock_invoice_based, deleted, warehouse_row, warehouse_column, warehouse_ledge, warehouse_id)
VALUES
(1, 0, "false", "", "", "", ""),
(2, 0, "false", "a", "", "", ""),
(3, 0, "false", "", "b", "", ""),
(4, 0, "false", "", "", "c", ""),
(5, 0, "false", "", "", "", 1);
```

And fiddle of same[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4255185/1)

This is the desired result:

```
+------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| product_id | warehouse_row | warehouse_column | warehouse_ledge | warehouse_id |
+------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|          3 |               | b                |                 |              |
|          4 |               |                  | c               |              |
|          5 |               |                  |                 | 1            |
+------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

This is my query

```
SELECT `product_id`, `warehouse_row`, `warehouse_column`, `warehouse_ledge`, `warehouse_id`
FROM (`shop_products`)
WHERE (`shop_products`.`stock_invoice_based` = 0 AND `shop_products`.`deleted` = 'false' AND `shop_products`.`product_id` NOT IN (42,45,46,48,52,82,86,123,173,176,181,196,196,202))
AND `warehouse_row` <>  ''
OR `warehouse_column` <>  ''
OR `warehouse_ledge` <>  ''
OR `warehouse_id` <>  ''
```

My current problem is that mysql returns also products where product_id is 45, 48, etc... So my shop_products`.`product_id` NOT IN is not taken in consideration

Please help me out with my problem. If you need any additional informations please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

Comment: @Strawberry didn't know that. Will do next time

Comment: That's true! :D will make one right now! ;)

Comment: @Strawberry there, added. Please remove downvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing parenthesis for your OR conditions. Otherwise your WHERE clause is true if any of the `OR` conditions is true (e.g. `warehouse_column <>  ''`)

```
SELECT `product_id`, `warehouse_row`, `warehouse_column`, `warehouse_ledge`, `warehouse_id`
FROM (`shop_products`)
WHERE (`shop_products`.`stock_invoice_based` = 0 AND `shop_products`.`deleted` = 'false' AND `shop_products`.`product_id` NOT IN (42,45,46,48,52,82,86,123,173,176,181,196,196,202))
AND
(
    `warehouse_row` <>  ''
 OR `warehouse_column` <>  ''
 OR `warehouse_ledge` <>  ''
 OR `warehouse_id` <>  ''
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra brackets!

You want the following:

```sql
SELECT `product_id`, `warehouse_row`, `warehouse_column`, `warehouse_ledge`, `warehouse_id`
FROM (`shop_products`)
WHERE (`shop_products`.`stock_invoice_based` = 0 AND `shop_products`.`deleted` = 'false' AND `shop_products`.`product_id` NOT IN (42,45,46,48,52,82,86,123,173,176,181,196,196,202))
AND ( `warehouse_row` <>  ''
  OR `warehouse_column` <>  ''
  OR `warehouse_ledge` <>  ''
  OR `warehouse_id` <>  '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if less typing is your thing, you can do...

```
SELECT product_id
     , warehouse_row
     , warehouse_column
     , warehouse_ledge
     , warehouse_id
  FROM shop_products p
 WHERE p.stock_invoice_based = 0 
   AND p.deleted = 'false' 
   AND p.product_id NOT IN (42,45,46,48,52,82,86,123,173,176,181,196,196,202)
   AND '' NOT IN(warehouse_row,warehouse_column,warehouse_ledge,warehouse_id)
```

(This makes an assumption about the negation logic which may be incorrect!)